# Graphics issues after migration from 12.04 to 13.10 with AMD graphics

Tags: drivers, ati, 13.10, launcher

I used 12.04 for a long time and all worked fine. Now i downloaded 13.10 and I think, graphics drivers doesn't work as they should.

Launcher doesn't hide (Although it's set in settings) and launcher size is still default when I set another value (I want it smaller). I have problems with youtube videos too.

I tried all three drivers in menu and all of them do the same. All previous versions worked fine. Can you please help, or should I downgrade back to 12.04? Graphics card is Sapphire 7750 OC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a link here:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2168460 that may help you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.